# Break y-axis in three parts in gnuplot

Tags: linux, gnuplot

I try to plot some data that has a huge gap in the y axis which I wish to exclude from the graph.

noises:
[image: noises]

I found [this](http://gnuplot-tricks.blogspot.com/2010/06/broken-axis-once-more.html) guide to split the graph into two parts, which works great for me.

```
reset
unset key
bm = 0.15
lm = 0.12
rm = 0.95
gap = 0.03
size = 0.75
y1 = 9.25e+06; y2 = 9.35e+06; y3 = 1.24e+07; y4 = 1.25e+07

set multiplot
set xlabel 'Number of Iterations'
set border 1+2+8
set xtics nomirror
set ytics nomirror
set lmargin at screen lm
set rmargin at screen rm
set bmargin at screen bm
set tmargin at screen bm + size * (abs(y2-y1) / (abs(y2-y1) + abs(y4-y3) ) )

set yrange [y1:y2]
plot 'upquValues.dat' title 'upper quartile', 'MedianValues.dat' using 1 title 'median value', 'loquValues.dat' title 'lower quartile',  'MeanValues.dat' using 1 title 'mean value';

unset xtics
unset xlabel
set border 2+4+8
set bmargin at screen bm + size * (abs(y2-y1) / (abs(y2-y1) + abs(y4-y3) ) ) + gap
set tmargin at screen bm + size + gap
set yrange [y3:y4]

set label 'Runtime [ns]' at screen 0.03, bm + 0.5 * (size + gap) offset 0,-strlen("PRuntime [ns]")/4.0 rotate by 90

set arrow from screen lm - gap / 4.0, bm + size * (abs(y2-y1) / (abs(y2-y1)+abs(y4-y3) ) ) - gap / 4.0 to screen \
lm + gap / 4.0, bm + size * (abs(y2-y1) / (abs(y2-y1) + abs(y4-y3) ) ) + gap / 4.0 nohead

set arrow from screen lm - gap / 4.0, bm + size * (abs(y2-y1) / (abs(y2-y1)+abs(y4-y3) ) ) - gap / 4.0  + gap to screen \
lm + gap / 4.0, bm + size * (abs(y2-y1) / (abs(y2-y1) + abs(y4-y3) ) ) + gap / 4.0 + gap nohead

set arrow from screen rm - gap / 4.0, bm + size * (abs(y2-y1) / (abs(y2-y1)+abs(y4-y3) ) ) - gap / 4.0 to screen \
rm + gap / 4.0, bm + size * (abs(y2-y1) / (abs(y2-y1) + abs(y4-y3) ) ) + gap / 4.0 nohead

set arrow from screen rm - gap / 4.0, bm + size * (abs(y2-y1) / (abs(y2-y1)+abs(y4-y3) ) ) - gap / 4.0  + gap to screen \
rm + gap / 4.0, bm + size * (abs(y2-y1) / (abs(y2-y1) + abs(y4-y3) ) ) + gap / 4.0 + gap nohead

plot 'upquValues.dat' title 'upper quartile', 'MedianValues.dat' using 1 title 'median value', 'loquValues.dat' title 'lower quartile',  'MeanValues.dat' using 1 title 'mean value';

unset multiplot
```

noises_break
[image: noises_break]

How Can I split it into three parts now? Also the legend and title of the graph does get lost, which I also would like to fix.

My next problem includes saving the graph as png or postscript. 
When I first use `set term png; set output 'img.png'` I generate an empty img.png file. When I plot first and set the term later and use `replot` only the upper graph is printed.

[image: break]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to "mimic" two axis breaks is to use `set multiplot layout 3,1` and to fix the y-ranges accordingly and to replot your data.

**Code:**

```
### two axes breaks
reset session
set colorsequence classic
set key left
set multiplot layout 3,1

set lmargin 5
unset xtics
set border 14
set ytic 1
set yrange [8:10]
plot x, sin(x)*10, -0.3*x**2+10

unset key
set border 10
set yrange [-2:2]
replot

set border 11
set xtics nomirror
set yrange [-10:-8]
replot

unset multiplot
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

To your other question:
If I use png or pngcairo or postscript terminal, I do:

```
set term pngcairo
set output 'img.png'
plot x
set output
```

If I omit the last `set output` I will get a file 'img.png' with 0 bytes.